# Kendo DropdownlistFor nullable bool not setting null value

Tags: kendo-ui, nullable, dropdownlistfor

```
@model bool?
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m=>m).BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
                                          new SelectListItem() {
                                          Text = "--Select--",
                                          Value = null
                                      },
                                      new SelectListItem() {
                                          Text = "Yes",
                                          Value = "true"
                                      },
                                      new SelectListItem() {
                                          Text = "No",
                                          Value = "false",
                                      }

        }).DataTextField("Text").DataValueField("Value").HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = "true" }))
```

Everything works with one issue: When I set a value to either true or false i cannot then set it back to null. So if the value of the field used to be "true" and i set it to "null" or ("--Select--") and click submit the value gets set back to false instead. This is how the field is set up in my model

```
[DisplayName("Autostart Load")]
public bool? AutoStartLoad { get; set; }
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Is this in a kendo grid?

Answer (score 2):

Try an `OptionLabel` property, it works for me

```
@Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.SomeProperty).OptionLabel("Choose value...").BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>()
            {
                new SelectListItem() { Text = "Yes", Value = "True" },
                new SelectListItem() { Text = "No", Value = "False" },
            });

public bool? SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

Also set the `Value` of `true` and `false` beginning with the capital letter, because `bool.ToString()` returns the values as `"True"` and `"False"`

Comment: did you actually test this?  It's not only not working but was even more broken when i capitalized the true and false.

Comment: @JohnLord the answer is 5 years old. A lot probably changed since then. Except the bool.ToString() is still capitalising it https://dotnetfiddle.net/ucgFry

Comment: well when you're bound to a model and the control is rendering the existing model value, it's evidently not doing a string comparison internally.  I don't know if THAT has changed, but it worked without capitalizing and didn't work with it capitalized.

Comment: Well, sorry to dissappoint :) I don't remember for sure, but i think it was working for me back in the days

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
@Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.SomeProperty).BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
    
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Choose value...", Value = "null" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "Yes", Value = "True" },
            new SelectListItem() { Text = "No", Value = "False" },
        });
```

It's not a problem specific to Kendo controls.  We have a similar issue with a custom 3-state option button group.  Nulls will not get posted unless you post them as a string.

In your original code, just put null in quotes.  That should fix it.